# Control Panel with Masked CP CORS issues

Tags: ee2, wygwam, multi-site-manager, subdomain, livelook

- MSM Setup
- EE 2.7.2

---

The site I am working on has masked CP access sitting on a subdomain of the site. This is a MSM setup in which the MSM sites are subdomains of the primary site.

Something like:

1. site.com
2. sub1.site.com
3. sub2.site.com
4. etc...

The masked CP access is setup so that each 'site' has its own location for the contributing groups to access independently.

So again, something like:

1. admin.site.com
2. admin.sub1.site.com
3. admin.sub2.site.com
4. etc...

All of the core files are located in the primary site admin folder (admin.site.com).

The site index.php files are in their respective site folders (site.com, sub1.site.com, etc...)

The admin.php files for the various admin folders has been renamed to index.php so that the contributing users can navigate to a clean URL of http://admin.sub1.site.com to get to that site segment's CP.

I am running into a lot of issues with resources not having permissions, CORS, etc. especially when using fieldtypes like wygwam when their is a NSM LiveLook tab. The NSM LiveLook tab errors with cross domain issues since it uses iframes to preview with when someone tries to use the embed media tool on wygwam.

Has anyone else run into issues like this? Are there any known solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved along with other issues that were determined as coming from the same source. There is a post [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15223/admin-control-panel-access-behind-firewall) which was related.